# iPhone UIAlertView Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ok so I have this code

```
NSMutableArray *smartThings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
NSMutableString *smartString = [NSString alloc];
int random;
int numOfThings = 1;
random = arc4random() % numOfThings;
smartString = [smartThings objectAtIndex:random];
UIAlertView *smartAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thing To Say" message:smartString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[smartAlert show];
[smartAlert release];

[smartThings release];
```

What it 'should' do is create a UIAlertView out of a string, and that string is created from an array of strings.

When I run it and press the button to call this code the program crashes. Please help

And yes i did hook up all the connections in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it this time. I had it in the MainView.m file instead of the MainViewController.m file.

Answer (score 3):

`smartThings` is empty throughout the execution of this snippet, even though you've pre-allocated space for 3 items, so `-objectAtIndex` will raise an `NSRangeException`, which would crash the program if not caught.

In addition, since `smartThing` is only intended to be a pointer to an object inside `smartThings`, you shouldn't `alloc` it, declaring it merely as `NSString*` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a few problems:

1. There are no strings added to smartThings, so  there's nothing for smartString to point to.
2. smartString should probably be declared as an NSString *, NSMutableString is for strings that you want to change the contents of.
3. numOfThings is totally redundant. Use [smartThings length] to find out how many strings are in smartThings

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I fixed it. here is my code

```
NSMutableArray *smartThings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"It's still intact, just in lots of little pieces.",nil];
    NSMutableString *smartString;
    int random;
    int numOfThings = 1;
    random = arc4random() % numOfThings;
    smartString = [smartThings objectAtIndex:random];
    UIAlertView *smartAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Smart Thing" message:smartString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [smartAlert show];
    [smartAlert release];
    [smartThings release];
```

But when I press the button to call this code the simulator crashes.